# Transform list in grid

Tags: php

I have this list of images:

http://thegelu.com/camera/ffffff.php

And I'd like the pictures to display as a grid, not like a list. (aka each pictures next to each other)

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
    $uploadsDirectory = 'slides/tail/'; 
    if ($handle = opendir($uploadsDirectory)) {
        echo '<hr/>';
        echo 'Official Backgrounds';
        echo '<hr/>';
        echo "<div class='bgitem' style='color:white;font-weight:bold'>None</div>";
        $uplo = array();
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            array_push($uplo, $file);
        }
        sort($uplo);
        $user = array();
        foreach($uplo as $fname) {  
            if($fname != ".." && $fname != "."){
                if(substr($fname,0,1) != "_")
                    echo "<div class='bgitem'><img src='slides/tail/$fname' height='30px'/></div>";
                else
                    array_push($user, "$fname");
            }       
        }

        echo '<hr/>';
        echo 'User Uploads :';
        echo '<hr/>';
        foreach($user as $div){
            echo $div;
            closedir($handle);
        }
?>
```

I'm a beginner in PHP so I don't exactly know what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to add some css to it if you want it to be shown as a grid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve a grid view using CSS. If you add the individual `.bgitem` items to a container, you can use the following CSS to achieve a grid view:

```
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

    .grid .bgitem {
        float: left;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

In turn, your markup should look something like:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="bgitem"><img src="slides/tail/1.png" height="30px"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zcro5acf/)